# Best way to level tops of a grid of screws in concrete floor

Tags: geometry

I have a large room (roughly 30' x 50') that needs a screed laying over crumbly concrete revealed by pulling up old wooden boards.

I was quoted $ 30,000 (or the UK equivalent) to drill up and replace the old concrete; but, although that would certainly be the best and fastest option, I need that money for other renovations at the rambling place I bought!

So I have decided to lay new screed by first planting a 3' by 3' square grid of screws across the floor, levelling the tops of all these relative to each other, laying lines of concrete between each pair of screws levelling the concrete against the tops, then pouring screed into all the squares formed by the concrete lines, and finally grinding and polishing the resulting surface flat. (The resulting pattern doesn't matter, as there will be a carpet over it.)

Obviously it is important to ensure as best I can that the tops of all the screws are in the same horizontal plane, and to do this I will be using a six foot spirit level to level adjacent pairs of screws relative to each other with a small laser spirit level taped to the top like a gun sight, sighting a red spot on a wall.

But the question then arises of what from a practical standpoint is the best order or procedure this should be done to minimize the risk of either level "drift" and/or inconsistent levels in some direction, *and* to avoid the possible requirement of so many downward adjustments that the screws end up almost level with the old floor!

I recall a Martin Gardner article explaining that a rectangular squad of soldiers could be ordered by height both front to back (FtB) and side to side (StS) simultaneously by ordering at most each row FtB, then each column StS, and each row FtB again, and it seems the present problem is a special case of that. Alternatively, would it be best simply to level screw tops in diagonal rows across the room?

It may well be this problem is trivial, and apologies if so. But one never knows, perhaps there are interesting and instructive principles involved, or pitfalls to avoid. So I would appreciate any constructive ideas or better still demonstrable results.

Comment: If there is no error in the leveling of adjacent screws, all the screws will be level so long as the set of screws that are leveled with the laser spirit is connected. If you allow error is leveling, and you want to minimize some measure of the unlevel-ness of the whole set of screws, that is a different question. You need to define your measure of unlevel-ness.